# Month year comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two input fields in which we enter Month-year. And display data in graph representation.
 Field1:Jan-2016
 Field2:Jan-2015

I have to compare and this fields and if Field1>Field2 then alert message has to display.

How to do the comparison in java script

Input type format is Month-year

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Can compare month using `index` of `months array`..And year using `Number comparison`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Could you please share the fiddle with example. I couldn't make itthis format.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this small sample in your code

```
var date_1 = new Date('2017', '01');
var date_2 = new Date('2015', '02');

if (date_1.getTime() > date_2.getTime()) {

  /* YOUR CODE */
}
```

**Update: 2016/04/21**

With `+` operator (more laconic):

```
if (+new Date('2017', '01') > +new Date('2015', '02')) {

  /* YOUR CODE */
}
```

By using `valueOf()`:

```
if (new Date('2017', '01').valueOf() > new Date('2015', '02').valueOf()) {

  /* YOUR CODE */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your strings and have a lookup for the month number and return the wanted comparison.

```js
function greater(f1, f2) {
    function getDate(f) {
        var d = f.split('-');
        d[0] = { jan: 1, feb: 2, mar: 3, apr: 4, may: 5, jun: 6, jul: 7, aug: 8, sep: 9, oct: 10, nov: 11, dec: 12 }[d[0].toLowerCase()] || 0;
        return d;
    }

    var d1 = getDate(f1),
        d2 = getDate(f2);
    return d1[1] > d2[1] || d1[1] === d2[1] && d1[0] > d2[0];
}

document.write(greater('Jan-2016', 'Jan-2015') + '<br>');
document.write(greater('Feb-2016', 'Jan-2016') + '<br>');
document.write(greater('Feb-2014', 'Jan-2016') + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the consistent string format of `"YYYY-MM"`, e.g. `"2020-10"`, `"2021-01"`, you don't even have to convert them to date for accurate comparison, just **compare the string value directly** if you just want to know which month is the later month.

Try this:

```
var d1 = "2020-12";
var d2 = "2021-01";

var greaterMth = d2 > d1 ? d2 : d1;

alert("Greater month is: " + greaterMth);
```

But for your case, that will be:

```
var d1 = new Date("Jan-2016");
var d2 = new Date("Jan-2015");

greaterMth = d2 > d1 ? "Jan-2015" : "Jan-2016";
    
alert("Greater month is: " + greaterMth);
```

You don't even have to bother about the **1st of the month** generated by the `new Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript Date object to compare your dates:

`new Date("Jan-2016") > new Date("Jan-2015") //-> true`

Comment: You'll get "Invalid Date" if you do that, Date can't parse that format.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should compare Date objects, but Date can't parse strings of the format you use.

If you format the date as "2015-01" and "2016-01" you can use Javascript's Date objects to compare them.

This gives you the benefit that you can continue to use these as actual date representations in your script, should you need to.

Note: if you format the date as, ex, "201501" and "201601" you can use simple greater-than or less-than comparisons instead.

So you need to:

1. Split the date string up into month and year
2. Convert the month string to an integer
3. Make a new variable to contain the formatted date
4. Compare the formatted dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

To get the date object, use

```
var date1= moment("Jan-2016","MMM-YYYY");
```

Similarly do it for second date and then just compare them as `date1 > date2`.